# Find interval pattern in set of intervals

Tags: algorithm, optimization, pattern-matching, intervals

Let's say I register a set of "on" intervals [tstart, tend]

`a = [[0+t, 3.9+t], [7.1+t, 8.0+t], [9.02+t, 10.2+t]]`

How do I find the best matching offset, t, for this pattern to match another set of intervals:

`b = [[5, 6], [7, 10], [11, 15], [18, 19], [20, 21] ... ]`

```
[ t  ]

      ----   - -

- --- ----   - - --- -- ----    - --
```

Comment: Maybe you could define "best"?

Answer (score -1):

Trivial algorithm (not neccessarily the most efficient):  choose all values of the offset t which cause one interval from each set to align in their starting or ending points. For each of these offset values compute the total overlap to find the max.  Complexity is O(n^3) where n is the size of sets (max of a and b). The overlap computation for a given offset is O(n), and the number of possible offset values is O(n^2).

In your example the offsets would be:
match beginning of interval a[0] to beginning of all intervals in b:

5-0=5, 7-0=7, 11=0=11, ....

match end of interval a[0] to end of all intervals in b:

6-3.9=2.1, 10-3.9=6.1, 15-3.9=11.1,....

We continue to do the same for all intervals in a, and collect all of the resulting offset values.  Then we compute the overlap for each of the offsets.

Answer (score -1):

You could define:

- [image: f(x,t) = 1 if x in a_t, 0 otherwise]
- [image: g(x) = 1 if x in b, 0 otherwise]

And compute:

[image: argmax_t (inegral on R of f(x, t)g(x)dx)]

Comment: Is there a convenient way to put latex formulas on here?

Comment: what ?? where are a and b ?

Comment: @gen-y-s defined by OP.

Comment: mmh ... I guess I'm on the wrong Q&A board to give math answers :/